# Using Solve[ ] inside a Module

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, scoping

I want to use `Solve[]` inside a `Module`. If I make the variables solved for local
to the module, they are treated differently than if I leave them global.
For example,

```
SolveIt[a_, b_] := Module[{x, soln},
   soln = Solve[a x + b == 0, {x}];
   Return[soln]
   ];
SolveIt[3, 4]
```

returns

```
{{x$1342 -> -(4/3)}}
```

If I leave `x` global, the function returns

```
{{x -> -(4/3)}}
```

But if that global `x` has a value, the `Solve[]` function says that `x` is not a valid variable.

Could someone please (a) explain what's going on, and
(b) suggest best practice for using `Solve[]` and similar functions
within a module. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can consider using a [formal variable](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264)? Those are guaranteed to never have anything assigned to them…

Comment: @J.M.  Mma formal variables are new to me. I will have to study to see how to use them in this context. Thanks!

Comment: Just to start you off: `SolveIt[a_, b_] := \[FormalX] /. Solve[a \[FormalX] + b == 0, \[FormalX]]`. (It looks gnarly on SE, but should paste fine into *Mathematica*.)

Comment: The problem is that if `x` has a value, it will evaluate immediately in an expression such as `x -> 1`.  There is just no good way to return something containing `x` if `x` has a value.  Do you really need to return `x` from the function (as part of a larger expression)?  Or is it sufficient to return the solution as a number, i.e. return `val` instead of `x -> val`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you really need to return `x` from your function (even as part of a larger expression)?  There is simply no good way to do this if `x` has a global value, as `x = 1; x -> 2` immediately evaluates to `1 -> 2`.

You could return the solution value only (`val` instead of `x -> val`):

```
SolveIt[a_, b_] :=
  Module[{x, soln},
   soln = Solve[a x + b == 0, {x}];
   x /. soln
  ]

SolveIt[3, 4]
(* {-(4/3)} *)
```

Using formal variable were mentioned.  These have the advantage that they are [`Protected`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Protected.html), therefore they are guaranteed not to have an assigned value.  So you might consider

```
Clear[SolveIt]
SolveIt[a_, b_] := \[FormalX] /. Solve[a \[FormalX] + b == 0, \[FormalX]]

SolveIt[3, 4]
(* {-(4/3)} *)
```

(Note: you can type `\[FormalX]` using ESC $x ESC.)

But there is a big problem with this.  This works fine:

```
SolveIt[a, 1]
(* {-(1/a)} *)
```

But what about this one?

```
SolveIt[\[FormalX], 1]
(* {-I, I} *)
```

We passed a symbol into the function, and that symbol happened to be already in use internally ... so we're solving the equation `x^2 + 1 == 0` now (compare to `a x + 1 ==0` before).

The same problem appears with `Block`:

```
Clear[SolveIt]
SolveIt[a_, b_] :=
  Block[{x, soln},
   soln = Solve[a x + b == 0, {x}];
   x /. soln
   ];

SolveIt[y, 1]
(* {-(1/y)} *)

SolveIt[x, 1]
(* {-I, I} *)
```

Thus it is important to use `Module` (and not `Block` or a formal variable) if you want to make it possible to pass symbols into the function.  If you only pass in numbers, this is not a problem, but then you may consider defining the function as `SolveIt[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ]`.

---

In case you are not certain about the difference between `Module` and `Block`, see here:

- [What are the use cases for different scoping constructs?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

In short, both localize variables, but `Module` does this by renaming them to a unique name (so that `x` becomes something like `x$123`) while `Block` just temporarily removed any definitions that may be associated with `x` (but `x` is still the same symbol as before).  Module emulates *lexical scoping* and Block does dynamic scoping.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, "it [is] sufficient to return the solution as a number."

Answer (score 3):

As explained in Mathematica help, "`Module` creates a symbol with name `xxx\$nnn` to represent a local variable with name `xxx`. The number `nnn` is the current value of `$ModuleNumber`."  This variable is not renamed after the module has completed.

If instead the variable `x` refers to a global variable which already has a value (e.g. `x=3`), the `x` in `Solve[eqn,x]` will be evaluated, so that it becomes `Solve[eqn,3]`  (leading to the message `Solve::ivar: 3 is not a valid variable.`

@J.M. suggests the use of [formal variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) which (I think) are intended for precisely this sort of use case.

```
SolveIt[a_, b_] := Solve[a \[FormalX] + b == 0, \[FormalX]]]
```